# Making a discussion board, how to have more people answer

Tags: php, mysql

im working on an Discussion board in php and mysql, but my question is; How can i make it that more than 1 person can react on a discussion, like at the moment i have that only one can react because it goes into a field in the database named; reactions

But i want ofcourse to have more people answer it instead of one...

If anyone could tell me how to achieve this, that would be a mayor help!

The code i tried so far:

```
<?php
include('inc/conn.inc.php');
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['post'])){
  $reactions= $_POST['msg'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO topics (reactions) VALUES reactions = :reactions";
$sql->bindParam(':reactions', $reactions);
$results = $conn->exec($sql);

}
?>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
  <title>Discussion Board</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Logo comes in here</h1>
  </header>
  <div id="t1">
    <h1>Featured</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="t2">
    <h1>Status</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="topic-items">
    <?php

    $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]);
/*
    $sql = "SELECT creator FROM topics WHERE id = :id";
    $sql->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $results = $conn->query($sql);
*/

    $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT message FROM topics where id = :id");
    $statement->execute(array(':id' => $id));
    $row = $statement->fetch();
    echo "Message: ".$row['message'];

    ?>
    <h2>Featured items come here {discussions} deployed by php </h2>
  </div>
  <div id="board-status">
    <h2>Board statuses come here {status} deployed by php </h2>
  </div>
  <div id="react-board">
    <form>
      Message:<br>
      <textarea name="msg"></textarea><br>
      <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post">
    </form>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <h1>Footer Content</h1>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Isnt it going to replace the field everytime someone presses on the POST button?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: You'll have to read more about database normalization. Answers/reactions should go to their own table.

Comment: i also have to learn how to make them link together in the PHP, when someone reacts the reactions go to the right post

Comment: +   $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO topics (reactions) VALUES (:reactions) WHERE id = :id");
  $sql->bindParam(':id', $id);
  $sql->bindParam(':reactions', $reactions);
  $sql->execute(); that is never going to work, INSERT doesnt support WHERE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first separate your tables in this manner:

[image]

Once you do that you can start creating queries using JOINs to obtain your data. Do this, then tell us if you have further difficulties.

Hope this helps.